# Separate Javascript file from View

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using `Codeigniter` and want to separate the JavaScript from the view files, but many of the JavaScript functions need data from controller (it depended on values from controllers)

ex:

```
controller :

function show_post() {
    $data['data'] = $this -> get_data();                 //some data
    $data['random_key'] = $this -> generate_random();    //returns a random value
    $this -> load -> view('posts', $data);
}
```

and in view I have a js function:

```
<script>
    function get_random() {
        return "<?= $random_key; ?>";
    }
</script>
```

How can I save this javascript snippets to some other file say `posts.js`? If I did something like this then I cannot use php variables inside the script.

What is the best way to achieve this in terms of Performance and Maintenance?

**Some other ways I do not want to follow :**

1. Save the JS file as a PHP file and then pass the values to that file
2. Declare all those variable in the view file globally

Comment: If it's not sensitive data I would just output the variable to the DOM as a data-id="id" attribute to it's corresponding html element, and then use javascript to interact with it from there. If it doesn't have a corresponding element, then chuck it in a hidden input box. Much cleaner.

Comment: i am not interested to change variables into html elements,it makes the DOM dirty.

Comment: I personally find your current approach of injecting php into javascript a lot dirtier than my alternative, or the alternative or doing a simple AJAX call. It sounds like your looking for a solution that doesn't exist outside of changing your framework/programming language all together.

Comment: @Jeemusu Thanks for your last words ,actually the idea is about to extend one framework ,so i cannot say how users will program and i need to provide the better way.Your methods will work in some areas (ex.binding a selectBox) and will not work for grouped items (A PHP OBJECT converted to Javascript Object) , the best way is use js object rather than converting to html elements.

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the value as parameter to your js function, like
post.js

```
function get_random( param ) {
    //use param here
}
//OR
function get_random( ) {
    //get arguments like
   var firstArg = arguments[0]; 
}
```

view.php

```
//include post.js file
//call the js function passing php variable as parameter, like
get_random("<?php echo $random_key; ?>");
```

did you mean something like this

Comment: If i integrated my js into another file , then for some reasons i cannot call like this.what will happen if i need the data in some events ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it by using hidden fields, in your case store them in hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random_key;?>" id="randomkey">
```

and access them in js by using ID like:

```
$("#randomkey").val();
```

In this way you can use controller paramter in your js.

Help it will help you!

Comment: Question is just an example , i cannot use this method in large methods.How can i store an array like this ?

Comment: @red If you don't like hiding the data in your DOM for later manipulation, it sounds like AJAX is your only option.

Comment: @sandip it will make another call ,this is worst than passing vars to php file (actually i need all these data in view file too and i do not want to create another call for JS)

Answer (score -1):

the simplest method is that , define php variables as js variable in your view file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var random_key = <?= $random_key; ?>;
</script>
```

then you can use that variable in your `example.js` file